# view group similar to chip group

Tags: android, view, android-viewgroup

Is there a View group similar to a chip group that just takes normal views?

I'm essentially after a kind of grid recycler view that doesn't scroll and instead just takes available space like a bunch of horizontal linear layouts inside a vertical linear layout, the reason I'm not just using a bunch of linear layouts is because I want to be able to count and select them like a chip group does, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

ok turned out just using a vertical grid layout manager on a recycler view with a height of wrap parent works exactly as i was looking for